# Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server on 000webhostapp.com

Tags: php, email, hosting, php-7, swiftmailer

In trying to send email using SwiftMailer.

```
$app['swiftmailer.options'] = array(
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => '465',
            'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'mypassword',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
            'auth_mode' => 'login'
        );
        $message = (new Swift_Message('Title'))
            ->setFrom(array('mymail@gmail.com'))
            ->setTo(array($mail_to))
            ->setBody($text);

        $app['mailer']->send($message);
```

This configuration works on my local virtual host. But when I deployed my application on **000webhost.com** I get an exception.

> Uncaught Swift_TransportException: Failed to authenticate on SMTP
>   server with username "mymail@gmail.com" using 1 possible
>   authenticators in
>   /storage/ssd5/070/4187070/public_html/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php:181

I didn't find any solutions for troubles on hosting services. Also I allowed access from unknown applications on gmail settings and visited *DisplayUnlockCaptcha*. That didn't help me

Maybe something wrong with the hosting service. Please help me to solve this problem!